# default margin a4 print

Tags: css

im creating a div wich can be printed.

it is going to be printed on 1 laying a4 paper.

i use in my css

```
width: 297mm; 

height: 210mm;
```

but if i want to print there are always margins on the sides (by default).

now if a user is going to print the div its going to be spread on 2 pages cause of the margins.

are there any default sizes for the margins so it's printable on every printer by default.

Does any ony know what these margins are so the user can print in on 1 page?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your block defined `display` style, I think this would be cover up your problem. Only defining width and height may float your element outside its container. So try doing this: `display: inline-block;` to your block. I think this will work.